# C# WPF Получить UI element который в Control Template в code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть Depedency Property

```
public DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(Card), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

public string Title {
  get => (string)this.GetValue(this.TitleProperty);
  set => this.SetValue(this.TitleProperty,value);
}
```

и в XAML есть TextBlock свойство Text которого биндиться к Title.
Можно ли не создавать DependencyProperty а сразу в get и set работать с TextBlock.Text? (если TextBlock внутри UserControl.Template)

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Вернее можно, но у этого свойства не будет функционала DependencyProperty, это будет обычное свойство.

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно пример? и какая разница в функционале?

Comment: Обычные свойства не поддерживают привязку, стили, триггеры, анимацию и т.д